# How to search contacts with T9 dialer on Nexus 4

Tags: contacts, nexus-4, phone-app

I had a myTouch Slide 4g rooted and running Android 4.0. I was using the default dialer that came with CyanogenMod's Google Apps ROM. I recently picked up the Nexus 4 (not rooted and the bootloader is locked), but it doesn't search through contacts when I put in numbers. Is there a way to use the default dialer to search for contacts by name or number?

Comment: This is [rumored to be an option in the dialer for Android 4.3](http://www.theverge.com/2013/7/18/4534690/android-4-3-jelly-bean-revealed-via-leak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now a standard feature of Android 4.3, although you do need to [enable it](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/50030/267).

From http://www.android.com/about/jelly-bean/

> Autocomplete - just start touching numbers or letters and the dial pad will suggest phone numbers or names. To turn on this feature, open your phone app settings and enable “Dial pad autocomplete.”

Comment: Yes, I was delighted when this update rolled out. Took away my last gripe with the unmodded Android OS.

Answer (score 1):

I was shocked by this as well, but apparently that's a custom feature from CyanogenMod, not available in stock Android. On unrooted phones I think the only hope is to install a custom dialer like [exDialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.modoohut.dialer).

References: [TalkAndroid](http://www.talkandroid.com/140885-three-flaws-google-needs-to-fix-to-make-stock-android-even-better/), [Xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1970213).

Comment: Is there no way to obtain CyanogenMod's apps without CyanogenMod?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Your answer was correct at the time of my posting this question, but is unfortunately no longer correct, so I updated the correct answer.

Comment: Ok! I'll leave it here for historical reasons.