# Android 4.3: How to get the dial pad autocomplete

Tags: phone-app, auto-correct, 4.3-jelly-bean

One of the most exciting features announced for the release of Android Jelly Bean 4.3 was the ability to get autocomplete when dialing a phone number in a similar fashion to text keyboard autocomplete from previous versions. I just updated my Android to version 4.3 but I don't see any difference with dial pad from previous versions.
Does that feature actually exist? Do I have to follow some steps to activate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this feature does exist, but it is disabled by default, so to enable it in a *vanilla* Android Jelly Bean 4.3 you must follow the steps below:

1. Open your **Phone** app, tap the dialer tab (first one at the left).
2. Tap the action overflow icon (at bottom right corner) and tap ***Settings***
3. Scroll down to section ***Other call settings***. You'll see the option ***Dial pad autocomplete*** is unchecked by default.
   [image: Step 1] [image: Step 2] [image: Step 3]
4. Check the ***Dial pad autocomplete*** checkbox
5. Go back to the dialer, now you'll see there is a slightly different layout than previously: the top area is now split in two different areas, shown in the picture as double arrows. The area with red arrow will show the phone number you are currently dialing as normally happens, but now the area with green arrow will show the autocomplete suggestions (contact name and their phone number) showing up to 3 contacts at the same time.
6. Start dialing a phone number and it will autocomplete both by contact name and by phone number as you touch each key. In the example it shows 3 suggestions: two by numbers 3-5-3 and one by letters corresponding to keys 3-5-3 (E-L-E)
   [image: Step 4] [image: Step 5] [image: Step 6]

If you don't feel comfortable with *dial pad autocomplete*, you can turn off this feature whenever you want by going again to ***Settings*** menu of the **Phone** app.